# Issue with modifying facts in kie-server

Tags: java, drools, kie-server

I am referring to the following code from the Drools documentation to modify the facts in Kie-server.

```
1 BatchExecutionCommand command = new BatchExecutionCommand();
2 command.setLookup("ksession1");
3 ModifyCommand modifyCommand = new ModifyCommand();
4 modifyCommand.setFactHandleFromString("123:234:345:456:567");
5 List<Setter> setters = new ArrayList<Setter>();
6 setters.add(new SetterImpl("age", "30"));
7 modifyCommand.setSetters(setters);
8 command.getCommands().add(modifyCommand);
```

In line 6, I would like to set an attribute to an object instead of string. For example,

```
6 setters.add(new SetterImpl("id", UUID.randomUUID());
```

However, SetterImpl(String accessor, String value) API only accepts String parameters.

Do we have any other implementation of SetterImpl which I can use to send object instead of String to Kie-server?

The reason why I want to send an object is that the java model within a container contains attributes that are of type non-primitive, for example,

```
Public class Test{
    UUID id;

    public UUID getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(UUID id){
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using an MVEL expression as the Setter's value. The code in ModifyCommand looks as if it were implemented. So, maybe:

```
6 setters.add(new SetterImpl( "id", "UUID.randomUUID()" );
```

This is evaluated in the session's context. You may have to import UUID in the DRL or use the full class name.

(I've never tried any of this, haven't used the command interface for years. I've just read the source code.)

Comment: Laune, your suggestion does not work! The problem is getMvelExpr() function within ModifyCommand class of the Drools-Core engine always converts the parameter into String. For your suggestion, the engine simply removes the quotes and append the value with key string.